# WrapperTop hook not working, prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I created a module that works correctly on my *localhost*, but when I install on my client server (same version of Prestashop, i.e 1.7), the hook **"DisplayWrapperTop**" does not work (i.e when I return a .tpl file in it or if I echo something nothing shows up).

I am looking for a way to debug this situation, or if you have the solution it would be even better.

Here is the code of the minimalist version of my module (where "WrapperTop" still does not show up):

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;


class TheModule extends Module
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'themodule';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'My name';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Le module test');
        $this->description = $this->l('Juste un essai');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to do it?');
    }


    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() OR
            !$this->registerHook('displayWrapperTop') OR
            !$this->registerHook('displayFooter')
        )
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()
            )
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    public function hookDisplayFooter($params)
    {

        print_r("hookDisplayFooter");

    }

    public function hookDisplayWrapperTop($params)
    {
        print_r("hookDisplayWrapperTop");
    }

}
```

Here, only the text "**hookDisplayFooter**" appears on the page, but not 
"**hookDisplayWrapperTop**".

Thanks

**p.s:** "I checked in the Design > positions, and my module is the only one present in displayWrapperTop